# Getting paths of qrc files in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qxmlstreamreader, qresource

I want to know how to access the paths of files in the qrc file in order to use them as strings in an array.
An example of qrc file is:

```
   <!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
    <qresource prefix="">
     <file>images/1.jpg</file>
     <file>images/2.jpg</file>
     <file>images/3.jpg</file>
     <file>images/4.jpg</file>
    </qresource>
   </RCC>
```

I want to use it in the following manner:

```
   for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
     path=image_path[i];
   }
```

where path is an qlist that can be later used for accessing the respective images.

Comment: Is this issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a simple way of doing it using [QDirIterator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdiriterator.html).

It might break if you have a directory called ":" in the current working directory and you expect that to be parsed instead in the future. Anyhow, that should not be a concern for now.

```
QStringList imageFileList;
QDirIterator dirIterator(":", QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while (dirIterator.hasNext()) {
    QFileInfo fileInfo = it.fileInfo();
    if (fileInfo.isFile()) // Do not add directories to the list
        imageFileList.append(it.next());
}
```

Alternatively, this requires quite a bit of involvement, but I think it works. I am afraid there is no more convenient way as of writing this.

#### main.qrc

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
 <qresource prefix="">
  <file>images/1.jpg</file>
  <file>images/2.jpg</file>
  <file>images/3.jpg</file>
  <file>images/4.jpg</file>
 </qresource>
</RCC>
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QXmlStreamReader>
#include <QString>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>

int main()
{
    QTextStream standardOutput(stdout);
    QFile file("main.qrc");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        standardOutput << "File open error:" << file.errorString() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    QXmlStreamReader inputStream(&file);
    while (!inputStream.atEnd() && !inputStream.hasError()) {
        inputStream.readNext();
        if (inputStream.isStartElement()) {
            QString name = inputStream.name().toString();
            if (name == "file")
                standardOutput << "file: :/" << inputStream.readElementText() << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
file: :/images/1.jpg
file: :/images/2.jpg
file: :/images/3.jpg
file: :/images/4.jpg
```

Comment: @user2828747: this code could also be improved with prefix and other fancy features if one wishes to go far.

Comment: If I have to store these paths read into an array, how to do that?

Comment: @user2828747: append the value of `inputStream.readElementText()` into that array inside the iteration?

Comment: I am having images in the qrc file. I want to display the images following a list-pattern when the application runs. Is this approach right?

Comment: @user2828747: yes, also, I added an alternative approach.

Comment: How to create a variable that stores the number of items in qrc file?

Comment: @user2828747: my code already shows that. In that scenario, you can use `imageFileList.size()`.