# How do I find the contents of a QResource directory, if I'm not allowed to call QResource::children()?

Tags: qt

The children() member function of QResource is protected. It does *exactly* what I need. (I have a collection of files in a certain resource directory, and want to use the list to populate a combo box.) Two questions:

1. Why is QResource::children() protected?
2. What's the correct way to do what this function provides?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844136/getting-paths-of-qrc-files-in-qt

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's certainly at least related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that QDir accepts qrc paths, so the equivalent of QResource::children() can be accomplished by calling QDir::entryInfoList().